# how to print "[" character in latex after \item[]

Tags: symbols

This is a very simple question, I am trying to print [ in latex it is giving me an error I tried [ but it didn't work. May someone help me see how to do so in latex?

Comment: `[` prints just fine as is.  You need to provide us a self contained code (called an MWE or "minimum working example") that demonstrates the issue.  Then perhaps, someone can help.  For example, I can think of a place where a `[` might behave non-intuitively, after a \\, but only an MWE can show us what you did.

Comment: Please show the error in a MWE. A basic MWE works fine for me. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/9595602pjrcskkrmqrc).

Comment: In math mode you can use \lbrack. In text mode use $\lbrack$.

Comment: Shouldn't you always be able to use {[}?

Comment: @JohnKormylo `$[$` won't necessarily give you the correct font if you want a `[` in text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX rsc05!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is indeed a good practice to add [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem to your question. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a template that has `\item[]` for some reason I can not write [ as is. I would like to thank all who tried to contribute especially @john kormylo that informed me that I should be using the mathematical code `\lbrack` and `\rbrack`

and `{[}`, `{]}` these work as well

Comment: I'm guessing you are using this in the following way: `\item [some] thing`, correct?

Comment: yeah correct I am in the \item[] part

Comment: The issue is that `\item` takes an optional argument, and optional arguments are usually specified within `[`...`]`. Using `\item{} [..] ...` will avoid capturing the first thing after `\item` as an optional argument. Other options also exist as you've noted.

Comment: you are right, but I do not want a bullet point after my words

Comment: it is nothing to do with any "template` but core latex syntax. Do _not_ use `$[$` if you want a text bracket, it will typically be using a different font.